# Connection Timeout for HTTPSURLConnection

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I am using HTTPSURLConnection from my java client to connect application server. It is observed that Connection is not timed out if Server Hangs.

Would you please suggest any way so that I can set the connection timeout after some specified time period. I tried setConnectTimeout() and setReadTimeout(), they are not working according to the method name.

Thank you in advance